# How to segment command script that is too big to fit into one transport APDU

Tags: sms, apdu, ota, sim-card, globalplatform

**SGP.02 - Remote Provisioning Architecture for Embedded UICC Technical Specification** (page 255 of v4.0 specifically) says:

> the data format provided by the function caller SHALL NOT depend of the selected OTA protocol capabilities (for example SM-DP can consider there is no limit on data length)

and later

> The SM-SR has the responsibility to build the final Command script,
> depending on eUICC capabilities and selected protocol:
>
> - by adding the Command scripting template for definite or indefinite length,
> - and, if necessary, by segmenting the provided command script into several pieces
> - and, if necessary, by adding the relevant Script Chaining TLVs.

I understand it that SM-DP can send arbitrary long `data` parameter to `ES3.SendData` and SM-SR should send several APDUs in multiple SMSes if `data` is too large to fit into one. And that is meant by `segmenting`.

The problem is I can't find a relevant specification that defines how segmenting should be done. And that's the question: where is the segmenting process defined?

I may be wrong but it seems that is not the same as Concatenated Short Messages described in the section 6.3 of ETSI TS 123 048.

It seems that Script Chaining briefly mentioned in ETSI TS 102 226 is somewhat related so pointers to the specification that defines how it works are also very much welcome (TS 102 226 talks about Script Chaining TLVs but not how to use them, at least I'm definitely missing some broader context how it works so any hints are appreciated).

UPDATE:

ES8.EstablishISDPKeySet function requires 3 APDUs to be sent. And they are quite big as they contain keys. From SGP.02-v4.0 table 150 I understand it that they are sent from SM-DP to SM-SR using Expanded Remote Command Format. The script in this format can be rather large as far as I understand (given that SM-DP can assume that there is no limitation on the data length). And it is not clear how SM-SR should `segment` it or use `chaining`. I'm just missing the specs where this is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The eUICC has a limited internal buffer, i.e. it cannot store a complete profile package of 10kb or more internally. The message must be chunked. If the eUICC supports just e.g. 1 kb then you have to split  the APDU commands after at most 3 APDU commands to stay below 1kb. The SGP.02 specification defines to have at least 1024 bytes. A fully featured SM-SR might store some attributes based on the eUICC vendor in the EID to add special handling and patches for certain eUICCs to support a larger buffer size.
2. Encode each APDUs chunk (1..n APDUs) into the Expanded Remote Command Format (ETSI TS 102 226, sect. 5.2.1) (compact format can only have one response for the last APDU, but if it works, you could save a few bytes)
3. Encode each Expanded Remote Commands message into a SMS-DELIVER (TS 123 048 and simalliance Interoperability Stepping Stones release 6) This includes the data encryption using the OTA keys (KiC, KID). [gsm0348](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/gsm0348) is a good Java library for this. Pay attention: For each message the OTA counter must be incremented. Select one reference number and keep it for all messages. I guess this is the identifier how the eUICC knows which messages belong together.
4. If using SMS (I would suggest to use CAT-TP or HTTPs instead -> faster and more reliable) encode it as SMS-PP Download message (TS 131 111). You will using message concatenation here if the payload is more than 140 bytes.
5. You will receive as response a SendShortMessage (TS 131 111, 6.4.10). Extract the user data again with TS 123 048 and simalliance Interoperability Stepping Stones release 6. You get the SMS Response message. Look into the response packet to get the user data.
6. Extract the user data as Expanded Remote Response (ETSI TS 102 226)

The eUICC will handle the streamed messages. The concatenated short messages are only used for a message chunk belonging together during the transit.

Comment: Thank you. I'm missing from the answer and specs what is `APDU chunk`. Where is it described?

Comment: I've added a clarification (I hope) to my question.

Comment: Chunk is not defined anywhere AFAIK. Maybe there is somewhere a minimum internal eUICC buffer defined which you can assume to be processed. You have to know it in advance. Assuming 1kb should be safe. But like said SMS is not the best option.

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear. When SM-SR receives long Expanded Remote Command Format (say longer than eUICC supports) how should it split that data into pieces? Do you want to say that when SM-SR get one large Expanded Remote Command Format script it needs to create several smaller scripts by splitting the list of commands into several lists of commands? And send them as individual messages over ES5?

Comment: Regarding the minimum size eUICC can support: that's not a question as this has the answer in SGP.02 for command TLVs (but I assume that the same applies for C-APDUs): `That block of data is split into segments of a maximum size of 1024 bytes (including the tag and length field). The eUICC SHALL support profile command data segments of at least up to this size.`

Comment: Great, then I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer gave me a lot of clues how to interpret the (rather vague IMHO) specification. I'm going to put my interpretation into an a separate answer to help people who struggle like me.

Comment: The specification is referencing a lot of ETSI and GP specifications. These again are referring to others specs. Everything is mentioned there somehow, but without having the complete picture too many unknowns can render the specification very vague.

Answer (score 0):

The best specification that kind of explains how segmenting and script chaining works in details is SGP.11 **Remote Provisioning Architecture for Embedded UICC Test Specification**.

It does not have a requirements per se but it has the byte level examples of incoming `ES3.SendData` and examples of the messages received by eUICC. And this allows to deduce the actual behaviour  of the SM-SR pretty easily.

And here is more detailed explanation with references to that specification.

### Command script

Command script is a list of commands sent in the data fields of the ES3.SendData. It can be (see `data` field description in table 150 of SGP.02-v4.0) either:

1. the list of C-APDUs commands (defined in `EXPANDED_COMMANDS` method on page 595 of SGP.11-v4.0 and uses in step 2 on page 407 of SGP.11-v4.0)
2. TLV commands that form a SCP03t script (defined in `SCP03T_SCRIPT` method on page 600 of SGP.11-v4.0 and used in step 14 on page 408 of SGP.11-v4.0)

### Script Chaining

Script chaining is the feature used when there is a need to execute several commands sent in multiple transport messages but when some context of the execution needs to preserved after the first command is executed and used for the next one (for example the first command is `INSTALL [for personalization]` and the second one is `STORE DATA`). This context is command session defined in section 4 of **TS 102 226**.

This is used at least in these cases (which is also supported by Annex K in SGP.02):

1. when the followup command is based on the response from eUICC
2. when command script is too large and cannot be sent in one piece

Script chaining is performed by SM-SR and is implemented by adding Script Chaining TLV to the command script in Expanded Remote format. See section 5.4.1.2 in **TS 102 226**.

Examples of script chaining can be found in SGP.11-v4.0.

For the first case see the scenario for **EstablishISDRKeyset** procedure in section 4.2.10.2.1.1 . For the second case see the scenario for **DownloadAndInstallation** procedure in section 4.2.18.2.1.1. The byte level representation of the script chaining is described in `SCP80_PACKET` method on page 601 (see option `CHAINING_OPT`).

It seems that explicit chaining is applicable only to `SMS` or `CAT_TP` transport. For `HTTPS` the command session coincides with the administrative session as defined in section 3.6 of **Remote Application Management over HTTP – Public Release v1.1.3** so there is not need to add explicit Script Chaining TLVs.

### Segmenting

When the command script is too large and cannot be sent in one piece SMSR generates multiple command scripts. The commands that SMSR received from SMDP `CMD1`, `CMD2`, …, `CMDN` (see step 14 on page 408 of SGP.11-v4.0) and that form a command script are split into several command scripts. The first one contains some initial portion of the commands `CMD1`, `CMD2`, …, `CMDi`. The second command script contains commands `CMDi+1`, `CMDi+2`, …, `CMDj`. The third one `CMDj+1`,…,`CMDk` and so on.

If `SMS` or `CAT_TP` is used then for every command a Chaining TLV is added to the beginning with the appropriate value (see section 4.2.18.2.1.1 in SGP.11-v4.0).

And then every new command script is sent in a separate message to eUICC.